# How to get value of Option in one line?

Tags: scala

Basically I want to do this:

```
val germanTranslation = translations.find(t => t.lang.equals("de")).get.value
```

But it might be that there is no such translation -> find will return None, and the get call will throw an exception.

So it seems it's suitable to use getOrElse. But don't know how it would work. Something like:

```
val englishTranslation = translations.find(t => t.lang.equals("en")).getOrElse("")
```

This one has 2 problems - `getOrElse("")` is trying to return a Translation or a String, this is incorrect, and, What I need is the value (String) of the translation - not translation object.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Option.map` to map your translation option to a string option, and then use `getOrElse` on the resulting `Option[String]`:

```
val englishTranslation = translations
    .find(t => t.lang.equals("en"))
    .map(_.value)
    .getOrElse("")
```

Answer (score 6):

No new answer, but because it is not yet mentioned here:

Since 2.10 the composition `Option#map . Option#getOrElse` can be replaced with `Option#fold`:

```
val englishTranslation =
  translations.find(t => t.lang.equals("en")).fold("")(_.value)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get value inside your option using map operation:

```
translations.find(t => t.lang.equals("en"))
            .map(_.value) // will get translation value if there is Some, 
                          // return None otherwise
            .getOrElse("")
```